# Accessing object properties from within another object (JavaScript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I am trying to access properties of a config object from within another object:

```
var myConfigObj = {
  $myCachedSelector: $('#mySelector')
}

var myObj = {
  $selector: myConfigObj.$myCachedSelector,
  url: 'http://www.someurl.com/somepath'
}

$.each([ myObj, mySecondObj, myThirdObj ], function() {
  this.$selector.load(this.url, function(){
  //do something
});
```

When trying to use $selector in the each function then, it returns "undefined". Both objects are in the same scope, and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Please add more code: what is `myConfigObj.$myCachedSelector` (maybe it's undefined)? And how are you using `myObj.$selector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code [worked well](http://jsbin.com/ojuko3) enough for me, with a few minor tweaks:

- This is probably the problem: Firefox is complaining about the semicolon, should be:

  ```
  var myConfigObj = {
     $myCachedSelector: $('#mySelector')
  }
  ```
- Should be in `$(document).ready`, of course.
- Missing some `});` at the end (probably a copy/paste thing)

Comment: Hi Kobi, thanks for your reply. These were all c&p mistakes :) But the code is still not working for me. I get this error message in IE: "'this.$selector' is Null or not an object" and still "this.$selector is undefined" in FF...

Comment: Kobi, I found the cause of the errors: there was one wrong property name hidden in my code. I also had another function inside each and so 'this' didn't point to the dom object anymore. 'This' can sometimes drive you a little crazy... :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox;
2. In the "Scripts" pane, set a breakpoint on the line that causes the error;
3. When stopped at the breakpoint, examine `this` in the right-hand "Watch" pane;
4. If the `this` object you're stopped on has a `$selector` property which has a `load` method then it's not the cause of your problem, so continue round the loop.
5. When the `this` object *doesn't* have a `$selector` property, or has one that doesn't have a `load` method, you've found your culprit. Now work out why you are sending it into that loop, or where you are failing to initialise it.